How to use supabase google auth provider in react naive expo app
I need to know how to use supabase google auth provider in react native expo app
i already trying to get Client ID using console.cloud.google.com but it is not provide Client Secret (for OAuth). in supabse, need secret id to active google provider. how to fix this?
enter image description here
I need answer to solve this problem
enter image description here

Hi @Suneth Udayanaga here is the link that you can refer to for the Google client id for the react-native expo link
